# How can I get screenshot quickly using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I using ffmpeg to get screenshot.
If the duration of a video 01:34:00(94min).
I use the following command:
`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 01:00:00 -t 00:10:00 -vf fps=0.1 ~/image%d.jpg`
to get screenshot from 60min to 70min of this video.
But ffmpeg will seeks in this input file to position, I can't get screenshot immediately. 
Is there a way to get screenshot quickly?

Comment: Place `-ss 01:00:00 -t 00:10:00` before `-i`

Comment: @Gyan Every time I run the command,I got image1.jpg image2.jpg ....How can I got images not start from 1. But from 50? So , I can get image51jpg,image52jpg.